# Validate TextBox not to contain Certain Values

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am in a situation where in my asp.net page the TextBox should **not** contain following values

**.Edit

.Delete

.ReadOnly**

So How to validate this using RegularExpressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use a single regularExpressionValidator and write

```
^\b((?!(Edit|Delete|ReadOnly)).)*$
```

LEt Me Know If That Helps

Comment: JazaKallah Brother,  This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom validator and check for each of these.

Comment: Sorry I actually need the RegulerExpressions for the same .. I have edited my Question

Answer (score 0):

try this in three RegularExpressionValidators

```
^((?!Edit).)*$
^((?!Delete).)*$
^((?!Readonly).)*$
```

Offcourse you can tailor the regex according to your need.